# Reuse function overloading in typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading

How to reuse function overloading in typescript?

For example, I have some function that is overloaded

```
function apply(value: number): number;
function apply(value: string): string;

function apply(value: any): any {
    return value;
}
```

And some other function that uses the apply function

```
function apply2(value: number | string) {
    return apply(value); // getting 'No overloads matching this call' here
}

const result = apply2(1);
```

Do I need to overload apply2, too?

- type of result must be number
- generics are not the option (an example is simplified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that type `number | string` is neither assignable to type `number`, nor to `string`. This way the compiler does not know which overload you're using in `apply2`, and thus it cannot tell you what the return type of `apply2` will be.

So, yes, the only way to solve this is by overloading the `apply2` function